# How do I get Unity to minimize windows individually, not in groups

Tags: unity

I am Ubuntu 11.04 user ( Unity gui ) but i have an issue : 
I am working on an exercise for my university and i must have open a lot of pdf files , when i minimize them , they minimized in a group on unity launcher and it is not usefull this
I would like to minimize them separately each window and not in groups . Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want each minimized window to get an own icon in the panel.

As far as my experience goes (and I greatly agree that this is a definite usability lack) unity itself is not capable of it. However another dock I used previously (`avant-window-navigator`) will do this for you and even display the pdf-preview images for each icon.
Whenever I have such a task to do, I launch `awn` additionally. It also features auto-hiding and workspace seperation, so you can have all the open PDFs on one workspace.

Another feasible workaround for the specific instance would be to have tabs in the pdf-viewer, but until evince supports this ([already requested](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/15899/)), you would have to use a different viewer.

Comment: no, actually, that's not necessary. You can use the Group and Tab compiz plugin to tab any windows. You can tab Firefox and multiple Evince windows, for instance. No problem.

Comment: +1 for another good option, however the group and tab feature of compiz is not too intuitive and even seems unstable from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

They actually do get minimized one by one. The launcher just hides it. I have an idea for you.

- 1) Do all your PDF work on one workspace.
- 2) Add a bottom gnome-panel with a window switcher. (The same one as we've used by default in earlier Ubuntus)
- 3) If possible, make the panel only appear on your pdf workspace, or just make a keyboard shortcut so you can show and hide it quickly.

For a good result, you should delete the default upper panel. You can do this using gconf-editor, or you can just log out, choose Ubuntu Classic session, delete the upper panel and log back into Ubuntu with Unity. You then make gnome-panel start with the session (you can do that in the startup applications dialog)